# Java / Android - Read, Manipulate and save XML file to internal Storage

Tags: android, xml, save, dom-manipulation

I'm developing an Android Application which will make use of an file System where Data will be stored in xml - files..

I'm successfully reading the according file and altering the Nodes (the Values are changed - if viewing in debugger) but no changes are made to my locally saved file..

Process:
1. Read/open local file                //done
2. Change DOM NODE                     //done
3. Save changes in my local file       <- fails

So far I know that I will have to use the TransformerFactory after following some Tutorials and other code snippets the changes are still not saved to my file..

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My Code:

```
try {
        File path = a.getFilesDir();
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(path.getPath() + "/" + FILENAME_PERMISSIONS);

        NodeList myCourses = doc.getElementsByTagName(NODE_COURSE);

        for (int i = 0; i < myCourses.getLength(); i++) {
            Node course = myCourses.item(i);
            Element e = (Element)myCourses.item(i);

            Node myPermission = course.getFirstChild();
            String name = e.getAttribute(ATTR_NAME);

            switch (name){
                case FLAG_CrossCult:
                    myPermission.setTextContent(boolToString(crossCult));
                    break;

                case FLAG_KAIROS:
                    myPermission.setTextContent(boolToString(kairos));

                    break;

                case FLAG_UnfinStory:
                    myPermission.setTextContent(boolToString(unfinStory));

                    break;

                case FLAG_EmpToInf:
                    myPermission.setTextContent(boolToString(empToInf));

                    break;

                case FLAG_YouthKairos:
                    myPermission.setTextContent(boolToString(youthKairos));

                    break;
            }

            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(path.getPath() + "/" + FILENAME_PERMISSIONS));
            transformer.transform(source,streamResult);





        }


    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e){

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(TransformerConfigurationException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: in Wich part of the code are you saving the new file?

Comment: Transformer transformer =     TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(path.getPath() + "/" + FILENAME_PERMISSIONS));
            transformer.transform(source,streamResult);

Comment: first of all, in your AndroidManifest.xml have you defined the permission:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: and what is? FILENAME_PERMISSIONS

Comment: 1. I m not writing to external Storage I'm writing to the internal Storage

Comment: 2. FILENAME_PERMISSION is my Custom String Flag which holds the name of my xml (courses.xml). As i said its a file System and i have to access the files in multiple activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem ...

The Code was almost correct.. 2 changes needed to be done:

1: need to use "new File()"

```
String myPath = path.getPath() + "/" + FILENAME_PERMISSIONS;
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(myPath));
```

2: I was writing to the wrong Node

```
//Node myPermission = course.getFirstChild();
//is now:

NodeList permissionList = e.getElementsByTagName(NODE_PERMISSION);
Node myPermission = permissionList.item(0);
```

I'll leave the question here incase someone needs to do the same..